# AngularJS ngRoute direct part access

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

My app works fine with ngRoute, but when I'm trying to access my parts directly(from address bar), it returns just the part (without main page). How to hide these parts from a direct access?

Explanation:
I have a site with 2 blocks. First is a menu and second is a content (one of my route's part). Menu has links: "#/main" and "#/account". When I press on the buttons, it works fine (left menu and content). But if I change URL from localhost:8080/#/account to localhost:8080/account, it renders ONLY content, without menu. I want to hide access to localhost:8080/account or make it to render a content with a menu.

Comment: Try to rephrase, not very clear what you mean at all.

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely not with your AngularJS routing, but the routing from the server. When you request a page like `localhost:8080/account`, your server says "ok, let's JUST deliver the `/account` file". But that's not quite right, because you actually want the whole app to load. It's a common problem, and not too bad to solve.

I don't know what your backend looks like, but here's a generic example with express/node:

```
var express = require('express'),
  routes = require('./routes');

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

"Every request to the backend should initially render the complete layout in order to load our Angular app. Only then will the client-side rendering take over."

src: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/backend-integration-with-node-express/implementing-client-side-routing.html