# Return partials from Spring controllers + integration with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, ngroute

After answer on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975774/angularjs-ngroute-direct-part-access) I have searched a lot of time and now don't know how to fix this problem:
How to return partials from Spring controllers (not whole page) for further integration with ngRoute. Main question was linked above.
PS: Template engine: Thymeleaf

Comment: What kind of templating language are you using, if any?  JSP?

Comment: I'm using Thymeleaf.

Comment: I would break your page down into fragments, and just return one of those as your view.

Comment: They are already broken, but when I returns one of a fragment from controller, it renders whole page, without navigation or something. Only content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Angular and thymeleaf, for avoid the render of the page what you can do is using directives like this:

```
app.directive("show", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            resolved: '=resolved'
        },
        templateUrl: '/detail.html' 
    };      
});
```

the html of the directive should start with something like:

```
<div ng-if="resolved">
<div class="col-md-10" ng-if="deviceDetail">
</div>
</div>
```

and in your template you can you the tag: `<show resolved="resolved" ng-cloak=""></show>`

Answer to the question:

In Thymeleaf+angular you dont work with different pages. You have one page and render part inside of it. So as you said pages 1, 2, 3.html and menu.

What I would do is have menu as a template of your page and then pages 1 to 3 are including depend of what are you doing on it.

Condition 1: If the information is coming from server or spring you do it on thymeleaf.
Condition 2: if you need to process information or interaction with the user used angular.

The code that I put you up there was for include pages as condition 2. If you need for condition 1 it is even easyer:

In your page:

```
<div layout:include="blah :: blah">Section that show</div>
```

New page (call blah.html) in the same folder as your page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div layout:blah="blah">
here code...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to implement this unsuccessfully. Can you extend the answer. On example, I have 1, 2, 3.html and menu. I want to switch between these pages.